# Cyclically Presented Groups.

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, group-presentation

*I suppose I've answered my own question in writing it but some input would be great.*

### The Question(s)

> What exactly are *cyclically* [presented groups](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group), what are some examples, and where might I find out more about them?

### What I have so far.

> **Definition 1**: *(This was found [here](http://math.oregonstate.edu/cyclically-presented-groups-and-circulant-graphs-and-matrices).)* Cyclically presented groups, such as the Fibonacci groups, are ones defined by a presentation with a cyclic symmetry.

This is okay, I guess, but I'm still not a hundred percent sure on the definition; what is meant by a "cyclic symmetry"? I suppose my next definition, which I found in [a paper by Prof. G. Williams](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6037/59853cd545f7ac52c3ab702af422bdaa36f8.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjYmp-YnqXVAhWHAcAKHU67DJcQFgghMAI&usg=AFQjCNGcFoEVe_zsMKl0UuaTzblAGOIRCA), explains it.

> **Definition 2:** Let $w=w(x_0, \dots , x_{n-1})$ be a word in the [free group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855321/different-ways-of-constructing-the-free-group-over-a-set) $F_n$ with generators $x_1, \dots , x_n$ and let $\theta$ be the automorphism given by
>
> $$\begin{align}
> \theta:& F_n \to F_n \\
> \, & x_i \mapsto x_{i+1}.
> \end{align}$$
>
> A *cyclically presented group* is a group $G_n(w)$ with the *cyclic presentation*
>   $$\mathcal G_n(w)=\langle x_0, \dots , x_{n-1}\mid w, \theta(w), \dots , \theta^{n-1}(w)\rangle.$$

---

As for examples, we have the [*Fibonacci groups*](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Fibonacci_group) given by the presentation
$$\langle x_0, \dots , x_{n-1}\mid x_ix_{i+1}=x_{i+2}\rangle,$$ which include the [Quaternion group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) $Q_8$ and the cyclic groups $\Bbb Z_5, \Bbb Z_{11}$, and $\Bbb Z_{29}$. They're $G_n(x_0x_1x_2^{-1})$.

We also have groups of Fibonacci type, $G(x_0x_kx_m^{-1})$, which include $SL(2,3)$, $SL(2, 5)$, and $\Bbb Z_7$.

---

As to where to find out more, there's [the last chapter of *"Presentations of Groups,"* by D. L. Johnson](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723497/expository-reference-on-group-presentations/1723502#1723502). This would be great but it's at the end of a book, so might not be accessible (at least for a while, like, say, a couple of months).

Please help :)

Comment: Yes the Fibonacci groups are certainly examples of cyclically presented groups. We have $F(2,3) \cong Q_8$, $F(2,4) \cong C_5$, $F(2,5) \cong C_{11}$, and $F(2,7) \cong C_{29}$. $F(2,6)$ and $F(2,n)$ for $n \ge 8$ are infinite. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22593 is an earlier post on this topic.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you. I've edited the question accordingly.