# There exist infinite solvable $p$-groups with trivial centre. (Use a hint.)

Tags: group-theory, p-groups, infinite-groups, solvable-groups, wreath-product

This is **Exercise 5.2.11** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsolvable-groups%5D+p-group+infinite), it is new to MSE.

This is marked as being referred to later on in the book.

Here are some previous questions of mine about Wreath products:

- [Showing $Z(H\wr K)$, for abelian $H\neq 1$ and arbitrary $K$, is the diagonal subgroup of the base group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4079892/104041)
- [Showing $Z(H\wr K)=1$, for abelian $H\neq 1$ and arbitrary, infinite $K$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4082857/104041)
- [Showing that the restricted wreath product $\Bbb Z\wr\Bbb Z$ is finitely generated.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4085628/104041)
- [The Frattini subgroup of the standard Wreath product of two quasicyclic groups is the group itself.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4339992/104041)

A question of mine that involves solvable groups is this:

- [The context & motivation for the Tits alternative in combinatorial group theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2638911/104041)

### The Details:

*(This can be skipped.)*

On page 12 of the book,

> The *exponent* of [a] group is [. . .] the least common multiple of all the orders [of its elements].

On page 24 of the book, paraphrased,

> An *elementary abelian $p$-group* is an abelian group of exponent $p$ which is a direct product of cyclic groups of order $p$.

---

On page 32 and 33 of the book,

> Let $H$ and $K$ be permutation groups on sets $X$ and $Y$ respectively. [. . .]
>
> If $\gamma\in H$, $y\in Y$, and $\kappa\in K$, define
>
> $$\gamma(y):\begin{cases} (x,y) \mapsto (x\gamma, y) & \\ (x,y_1) \mapsto (x,y_1) & y_1\neq y,\end{cases}$$
> and
>
> $$\kappa^\ast: (x,y)\mapsto (x,y\kappa).$$
>
> [. . .] The functions $\gamma\mapsto \gamma(y)$, with $y$ fixed, and $\kappa\mapsto \kappa^\ast$ are monomorphisms from $H$ and $K$ to ${\rm Sym}(X\times Y)$: let their images be $H(y)$ and $K^\ast$, respectively. Then the *wreath product* of $H$ and $K$ is the permutation group on $X\times Y$ [. . .]
>
> $$H\wr K=\langle H(y), K^\ast\mid y\in Y\rangle.$$

---

On page 41 of the book,

> If $H$ and $K$ are arbitrary groups, we can think of them as permutation groups on their underlying sets via the right regular representation and form their wreath product $W=H\wr K$: this is called the *standard wreath product*.

---

For a prime $p$, an *infinite $p$-group* is an infinite group all of whose elements have orders a power of $p$ (not necessarily the same).

---

On page 121,

> A group $G$ is said to be *soluble* (or *solvable*) if it has an *abelian series*, by which we mean a series $1=G_0\lhd G_1\lhd\dots \lhd G_n=G$ in which each factor $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is abelian.

### The Question:

> There exist infinite solvable $p$-groups with trivial centre. [*Hint:* Consider the standard wreath product $\Bbb Z_p\wr E$ where $E$ is an infinite elementary abelian $p$-group.]

*I am more concerned with the hint than with providing any (other) example of such a group. Also, $\Bbb Z_p$ is the cyclic group of order $p$.*

### Thoughts:

Let $G=\Bbb Z_p\wr E$. Then $G$ is nonabelian.

---

Let $p=2$.

After a quick search online, I found via [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_abelian_group), that the group $(\mathcal{P}(\Bbb Z),\Delta)$, where $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference $X\Delta Y=(X\setminus Y)\cup(Y\setminus X)$ on arbitrary $X,Y$ in the power set $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb Z)$ of $\Bbb Z$, is an infinite elementary abelian $2$-group, since each nontrivial element has order two.

Therefore, let $E=(\mathcal{P}(\Bbb Z),\Delta)$. Then $G=\Bbb Z_2\wr E$.

Clearly $G$ is infinite.

I need to show $G$ is solvable.

Let $g\in Z(G)$. I need to show $g=e$.

I'm not sure how to handle this case of the hint, let alone the hint in its entirety.

---

Please help :)

Comment: I suppose that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ means the cyclic group of order $p$? Also, on what sets are these groups supposed to act? Themselves?

Comment: Yes, @Mindlack; it's the cyclic groups of order $p$.  Thank you for pointing out the issue of what the groups act on. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: The lamplighter group $C_2\wr \mathbb Z$ is an example. If $E$ is the direct product of infinitely many copies of $C_2$, then  $C_2\wr \mathbb E$ is an example too.

Comment: Unless I’m mistaken, your $\gamma(y)$ all commute, and they generate a normal subgroup. But the quotient by said subgroup is abelian. No?

Comment: I agree that the $\gamma(y)$ commute, @Mandlack, but I don't see right away how they generate a normal subgroup nor how the quotient is abelian. I'll think about it. Thank you.

Comment: @Shaun: the conjugate of $\gamma(y)$ by $\kappa^*$ is of the form $\gamma(y’)$ with $y’=y\kappa^{\pm 1}$, no? As for the quotient (if the first part is correct), it is merely generated by the image of $K$ so it is abelian.

Comment: @Mindlack: I see. Thank you. However, something has escaped my understanding. Are you saying $$1\lhd \langle \gamma(y)\mid y\in K\rangle \lhd H\wr K$$ is an abelian series in general? Because that doesn't seem right. If not, where have you used the properties of $\Bbb Z_p$ and of $E$?

Comment: @Shaun: I *think* that I merely used abelian-ness (so we get your comment’s claim), but it’s very possible that I missed something. I’m not a group theorist by any means so I don’t have any intuition on what wreath products are apart from the formal definition.

Comment: If $G=H\wr K$ (and I seem to remember we ran into an issue of whether Robinson uses the restricted direct product or the cartesian as the base; he uses the restricted product), then by construction the "base group" (the product of copies of $H$ Indexed by $K$) is normal in $G$. If $H$ and $K$ are abelian, then $G$ is solvable, because the base group is abelian and normal, and the quotient is isomorphic to $K$, which is abelian. Then you just need to show that this example has trivial center, which is not hard.

Comment: In fact, you already link to a question showing that $Z(H\wr K)$ is trivial when $H$ is abelian and $K$ is infinite, so aren't you done?

Comment: (If you use the cartesian, then it is no longer true that the center is trivial in this situation, since the subgroup of the base group consisting of constant functions/tuples would be central...)

Comment: Thank you, @ArturoMagidin. Please would you type that up as an answer, so that I may close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that Robinson defines the (restricted) wreath product $H\wr K$ to be the split extension of the restricted direct product (I will borrow the notation from Hungerford) ${\prod\limits_{k\in K}}^*H$ of $|K|$ copies of $H$ by $K$. The restricted direct product is the set of (set theoretic) functions $f\colon K\to H$ of finite support, with coordinatewise multiplication. The [linked to question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4079892/742) contains the explicit description, so I won't repeat it here.

In particular, in the wreath product $H\wr K$, the subgroup ${\prod\limits_{k\in K}}^*H$ is normal, and the quotient of $H\wr K$ by this subgroup is isomorphic to $K$.

In the case at hand, $H$ and $K$ are abelian; thus, $H\wr K$ is metabelian (extension of an abelian group by an abelian group) and thus solvable. If $H\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $K$ is an (infinite) elementary abelian $p$-group, it is not hard to verify that every element has order a power of $p$, so $H\wr K$ is a $p$-group.

When $K$ is infinite and $H$ is abelian, [you already proved that $Z(H\wr K)=\{1\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4082857/742). Thus, $\mathbb{Z}_p\wr E$ where $E$ is an infinite elementary abelian group is (i) metabelian, hence solvable; (ii) a $p$-group; (iii) with trivial center.