# How is $ F(2,m) = \langle a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_m \mid a_i a_{i+1} = a_{i+2} \rangle $ a group?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

A Fibonacci group is defined as the group with the presentation
$$ F(2,m) = \langle a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_m \mid a_i a_{i+1} = a_{i+2} \rangle $$
where the indexes are reduced modulo $m$.

Can someone describe how this a group ?
Please post some other references.

Comment: Where do you have this concept from? (and what does that notation even mean?)

Comment: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fibonacci_group

Comment: Consider the free group $G$ on generators $a_1,\ldots, a_n$. In it, let $N$ be the smallest normal subgroup $N$ that contains all $a_ia_{i+1}a_{i+2}^{-1}$. Then $F(2,m)=G/N$.

Comment: @user157835: You were missing the angle brackets, and it would be nice to have stated explicitly that this was supposed to be a group presentation.

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2371585/104041)

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

Let $F$ be the free group on $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^m$. Quotient out by the normal subgroup $N$ generated by the relations $a_ia_{i+1}=a_{i+2}$ (*i.e.*, the elements (or "relators") $a_ia_{i+1}a_{i+2}^{-1}$), taking the subscripts modulo $m$. The resulting group $G\cong F/N$ is the group defined by your group presentation.

Such a description is typical (and in fact a definition of) a [group presentation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupPresentation.html).

---

For a reference, you can't get more comprehensive than [this survey of Fibonacci groups](http://repository.essex.ac.uk/3801/).

Comment: Is it clear what "the normal subgroup generated by the relations $a_ia_{i+1}=a_{i+2}$" means? It is actually the normal subgroup generated by the elements $a_ia_{i+1}a_{i+2}^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you, @DerekHolt. I've edited it now.